# How to reload the datatable(jquery) data?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to reload the selected tab? Actually I have problem with reloading part. When I add my data I'll successfully saved in datatable but in id field in database it shows proper id, but when I add the detail its not shows id in datatable.

(before refresh the summary tab) here is example it shows something like this in datatable id patient husband age ...........so on... '' xyz abc 23....... so on...

(after refreshing manually) but when I refresh my page it show successfully..like this in datatable: id patient husband age ...........so on... 13 xyz abc 23 ....... so on...

But exactly I want when I add my detail it should automatically refresh the selected tab.

My code is below:

```
<button type="button"  a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnClickAddRow();">Add Summary</button>

function fnClickAddRow(event) {

$('#table_scroll').dataTable().fnAddData( [

$('#patientt').val(),$('#husband').val(),$('#age').val(),$('#opu_no').val(),$('#date').val(),$('#proc').val(),$('#no_of_eggs').val(),$('#fert').val(),$('#et_date').val(),$('#et_day').val(),$('#et').val(),$('#fz').val(),$('#bioch_preg').val(),$('#clin_preg').val(),$('#fh').val(),$('#comment').val()

]);


var datastring = $(Form_summary).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "summaryajax.php",
    data: datastring, 
    success: function(response){

 alert(response);

    }
    });
```

I also tired this approach but no success.

I want my datatable to refresh the data

```
function fnClickAddRow(event) {

var datastring = $(Form_summary).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "summaryajax.php",
    data: datastring, 
    success: function(response){
       $('#table_scroll').dataTable().fnAddData( 
          [resposne, $('#patientt').val(), $('#husband').val(),$('#age').val(),
            $('#opu_no').val(), $('#date').val(),$('#proc').val(), $('#no_of_eggs').val(), 
            $('#fert').val(),$('#et_date').val(), $('#et_day').val(), $('#et').val(), 
            $('#fz').val(), $('#bioch_preg').val(), $('#clin_preg').val(), $('#fh').val(), 
            $('#comment').val() ]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use a simple approach...

```
$('YourDataTableID').dataTable()._fnAjaxUpdate();
```

It will refresh the data by making an ajax request with the same parameters. Very simple.

Comment: Doesn't work for me; it makes the back-end call and gets the data but doesn't recreate the table itself. :(

Comment: dude, you are a major life saver! this works perfectly for me. +100

Answer (score 19):

You could use this function:

```
function RefreshTable(tableId, urlData)
    {
      //Retrieve the new data with $.getJSON. You could use it ajax too
      $.getJSON(urlData, null, function( json )
      {
        table = $(tableId).dataTable();
        oSettings = table.fnSettings();

        table.fnClearTable(this);

        for (var i=0; i<json.aaData.length; i++)
        {
          table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
        table.fnDraw();
      });
    }
```

Dont' forget to call it **after** your delete function has succeded.

Source: http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/?p=536

Comment: Great solution no need for FN... fnReloadAjax!

Answer (score 13):

Use [the fnReloadAjax()](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) by the DataTables.net author.

I'm copying the source code below - in case the original ever moves:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )
{
    if ( typeof sNewSource != 'undefined' && sNewSource != null )
    {
        oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
    }
    this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, true );
    var that = this;
    var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
    var aData = [];

    this.oApi._fnServerParams( oSettings, aData );

    oSettings.fnServerData( oSettings.sAjaxSource, aData, function(json) {
        /* Clear the old information from the table */
        that.oApi._fnClearTable( oSettings );

        /* Got the data - add it to the table */
        var aData =  (oSettings.sAjaxDataProp !== "") ?
            that.oApi._fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )( json ) : json;

        for ( var i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ )
        {
            that.oApi._fnAddData( oSettings, aData[i] );
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
        that.fnDraw();

        if ( typeof bStandingRedraw != 'undefined' && bStandingRedraw === true )
        {
            oSettings._iDisplayStart = iStart;
            that.fnDraw( false );
        }

        that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false );

        /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
        if ( typeof fnCallback == 'function' && fnCallback != null )
        {
            fnCallback( oSettings );
        }
    }, oSettings );
}

/* Example call to load a new file */
oTable.fnReloadAjax( 'media/examples_support/json_source2.txt' );

/* Example call to reload from original file */
oTable.fnReloadAjax();
```

Comment: fnReloadAjax() worked perfectly. I didn't find this solution anywhere. It keeps all active filter and sorting. Just perfect.

Comment: This is a good way of doing it. Works perfectly, but it seems to me that Elior Cohen's answer is better. The result is the same, but it doesn't require any kind of extra code, just a simple datatables method call. Go for $('YourDataTableID').dataTable()._fnAjaxUpdate();

Comment: In principle similar logic was added to DataTable v1.10.1 as [`ajax.reload()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29).

Answer (score 8):

Simpler solution:

```
var dt = $('#table_scroll').dataTable();

$.getJSON(url, null, function (json) {
    dt.fnClearTable();
    dt.fnAddData(json.aaData);
    dt.fnDraw();
});
```

Comment: The most elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: The most elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If anything works! Do this:

example:

```
<div id="tabledisplay"><table class="display" id="table"></table><table </div>
```

how to reload the table:

```
$('#tabledisplay').empty();
$('#tabledisplay').append("<table class=\"display\" id=\"table\"></table>");
initTable( "tablename");
```

initTable is just a method, that initialized the Table with getJSON.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (sort of).

Answer (score 3):

None of these solutions worked for me, but I did do something similar to Masood's answer. Here it is for posterity. This assumes you have `<table id="mytable"></table>` in your page somewhere:

```
function generate_support_user_table() {
        $('#mytable').hide();
        $('#mytable').dataTable({
            ...
            "bDestroy": true,
            "fnInitComplete": function () { $('#support_user_table').show(); },
            ...
        });
}
```

The important parts are:

1. `bDestroy`, which wipes out the current table before loading.
2. The `hide()` call and `fnInitComplete`, which ensures that the table only appears after everything is loaded. Otherwise it resizes and looks weird while loading.

Just add the function call to `$(document).ready()` and you should be all set. It will load the table initially, as well as reload later on a button click or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Get the url from the Settings of the table: oSettings.sAjaxSource

function refreshTable(oTable) {
    table = oTable.dataTable();
    oSettings = table.fnSettings();

    //Retrieve the new data with $.getJSON. You could use it ajax too
    $.getJSON(oSettings.sAjaxSource, null, function( json ) {
        table.fnClearTable(this);

        for (var i=0; i<json.aaData.length; i++) {
            table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
        table.fnDraw();
    });
}
```

Comment: have you ever heard of for(var i in json.aaData)

Comment: What is this needed for?  `oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();`

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this just in case someone need it..

Just create a button:

```
<button type="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="mytable.fnDraw();">Refresh</button>
```

but don't forget to add this when calling the datatable:

```
mytable = $("#mytable").dataTable();
```

Comment: It won't work if the `dataTable` has already been initialized. It will throw an exception in that case.

Answer (score 1):

To reload the table data from Ajax data source, use the following function:

```
dataTable.ajax.reload()
```

Where `dataTable` is the variable used to create the table.

```
var dataTable = $('#your_table_id').DataTable({
     ajax: "URL"
});
```

See [`ajax.reload()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For the newer versions use:

```
var datatable = $('#table').dataTable().api();

$.get('myUrl', function(newDataArray) {
    datatable.clear();
    datatable.rows.add(newDataArray);
    datatable.draw();
});
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27781459/4059810