# How to change a django_tables2 table dynamically on ajax request

Tags: javascript, django, django-tables2

I want my django_tables2 table to be able to add new rows at the top as new data comes in from the server (possibly by polling, or possibly via a push). I don't want to do a server page refresh, just scroll the existing rows down and add the new rows at the top.

I know I can just set up a periodic refresh from the server but that's not what I want to do.

Is this possible?  After much searching, I have not found any reference to doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a great tool, but it is built around a classical notion of doing everything on the server side.
If you find yourself reaching out to band-aiding custom ajaxy solutions on top of it, I would recommend you to look into going with [django-eztables](http://django-eztables.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead.

This library effectively gives you out-of-the-box integration with [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/), which is a rock-solid framework.

After installing `eztables` you'll instantly be able to update table data [without refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432801/497056) the whole page and also keep the user-selected filtering an sorting (and easily do much, much more).  I personally use `eztables`, they are quite modern, but nevertheless well-tested and robust.

Comment: I agree with the django-eztables approach. Also, another alternative is https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view which is another way to integrate datatables with django.

Comment: @Serafeim, thanks for suggestion! I'll definitely take a look at this one!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be, I think, [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). Just add your data from an ajax request,