# jquery.Datatables - Rebinding table data on form submit

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I am using the jQuery plugin DataTables and so far it has been pretty easy to figure out.

one issue I am getting stuck on is rebinding the table after I add a new record.

I have a modal which has a form and after everything processes, I'd like to close the modal and reload the data for the table.

I seen that there is a built in function for this, but it does not seem to be working, possible because the JavaScript. variable isn't available to the modal code.

Has anyone successfully been able to do this? If you need me to whip up a fiddle page, I'll be happy to.

**EDIT:**

To add more content to this post. I populate my table using ajax and I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.

Comment: what type of modal, how do you initialize the dataTable and so on. Really hard to guess what you want :)  I have created this fiddle for you, using a bootstrap modal and dataTables 1.10.x -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j7ADS/** does that answer your question?

Comment: that actually does, thanks :)

Comment: I found an answer to my problem on an [existing question][1].
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12876457/778587