# Reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have build a filter in my DataTable so I can check for the status. I am using the following code to retrieve the status:

```
    if(isset($_POST['status']))
    {
        if (!empty($where) ) {
         $where .= "AND status = '". $_POST['status'] ."'";
        } else {
         $where .= "WHERE status = '". $_POST['status'] ."'";
        }
    }
    else{
        if (!empty($where) ) {
         $where .= "AND status = '1'";
        } else {
         $where .= "WHERE status = '1'";
        }
    }
```

I have no issues with selecting the data. When I look at the WebConsole I can see that the script is posting the right data en gets the right response.

But I have some issues with the presentation of the data.

When the response is correct I want to update my DataTable.

I am using the following code for updating my datatable:

```
      success:function(data){
        $('#tb1').DataTable(data);
      }
```

When I execute this code I get a DataTables warning:

`DataTables warning: table id=tb1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.`

I cant figure out whats wrong with my script. Looking to multiple examples the script should work. Does someone know what is wrong with my script and how I can solve this problem?

Here is my full script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#tb1').DataTable({
       "bprocessing": true,
       "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
    "url": "./Response1.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "error": function(){
    $("#grid_processing").css("display","none");
    }
    }     
      });   
      $("div.toolbar1").html('<select id="status" type="status"><option value="1">Active</option><option value="0">Inactive</option></select>');

      $("#status").on('change',function () {

    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: './Response1.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'status='+val,
      success:function(data){
        $('#tb1').DataTable(data);
      }
    });
      });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Comment: I tried all these options. The only 'working' option was the `table.destroy();` function. It did change the layout of my datatable, but it didnt change the data in my datatable

Comment: What are you expecting from your ajax request?

Comment: @John, destroy is used only to change some options of table, to refresh data you do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778389

Answer (score 1):

**Updated with explanation and references**

There is no need separate Ajax request. Stick with [Datatables Ajax option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) is enough.

We can use Datatables  [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option to `add additional data` to the request, or `to modify the data object` being submitted to server if required.

To work with `new and refresh data input` we need to use `ajax.data as a function` otherwise it will initialized as a static object which will evaluated only once.

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "data": function ( data) {
        //your data altering codes
    }
  }
} );
```

And then use Datatables [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) to reload the table data from the Ajax data source within your event calls.

Possible ways to update data request using Datatables [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) is by:

1. Using element value directly

> ```
> var table = $('#example').dataTable({
>     "ajax": {
>         "url": "data.json",
>         "data": function(data) {
>             data.status = $('#status').val();
>         }
>     }
> });
> table.ajax.reload();
> ```

2. Using global variable that can be changed inside event call before Datatables [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

> ```
> var global_status = 1;
> var table = $('#example').dataTable({
>     "ajax": {
>         "url": "data.json",
>         "data": function(data) {
>             data.status = global_status;
>         }
>     }
> });
>
> $("#status").on('change', function() {
>     global_status = $(this).val();
>     table.ajax.reload();
> });
> ```

**Sample demo:**

```js
$.mockjax({
    url: "Response1.php",
    response: function(settings) {
        // Investigate the `settings` to determine the response...
        if (settings.data.status == 1) {
            this.responseText = {
                "draw": settings.data.draw,
                "recordsTotal": 57,
                "recordsFiltered": 57,
                "data": [
                    [
                        "Airi",
                        "Satou",
                        "Accountant",
                        "Tokyo",
                        "28th Nov 08",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Angelica",
                        "Ramos",
                        "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
                        "London",
                        "9th Oct 09",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Ashton",
                        "Cox",
                        "Junior Technical Author",
                        "San Francisco",
                        "12th Jan 09",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Bradley",
                        "Greer",
                        "Software Engineer",
                        "London",
                        "13th Oct 12",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Brenden",
                        "Wagner",
                        "Software Engineer",
                        "San Francisco",
                        "7th Jun 11",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Brielle",
                        "Williamson",
                        "Integration Specialist",
                        "New York",
                        "2nd Dec 12",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Bruno",
                        "Nash",
                        "Software Engineer",
                        "London",
                        "3rd May 11",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Caesar",
                        "Vance",
                        "Pre-Sales Support",
                        "New York",
                        "12th Dec 11",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Cara",
                        "Stevens",
                        "Sales Assistant",
                        "New York",
                        "6th Dec 11",
                        "1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Cedric",
                        "Kelly",
                        "Senior Javascript Developer",
                        "Edinburgh",
                        "29th Mar 12",
                        "1"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
        if (settings.data.status == 0) {
            this.responseText = {
                "draw": settings.data.draw,
                "recordsTotal": 57,
                "recordsFiltered": 57,
                "data": [
                    [
                        "Airi",
                        "Satou",
                        "Accountant",
                        "Tokyo",
                        "28th Nov 08",
                        "0"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Angelica",
                        "Ramos",
                        "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
                        "London",
                        "9th Oct 09",
                        "0"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Ashton",
                        "Cox",
                        "Junior Technical Author",
                        "San Francisco",
                        "12th Jan 09",
                        "0"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});



$(document).ready(function() {
    var req_status = 1;
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "searching": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "Response1.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function(data) {
                data.status = req_status;
            }
        },
    });

    $("div.toolbar1").html('<select id="status" type="status"><option value="1">Active</option><option value="0">Inactive</option></select>');

    $("#status").on('change', function() {
        req_status = $(this).val();
        table.ajax.reload();
        console.log('Status Val',table.ajax.params().status);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.6.2/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="toolbar1"></div>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#tb1").dataTable().fnDestroy();
$("#tb1").html(data);
$("#tb1").DataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after serverside: true,

```
destroy: true
```

to destroy the table after its initialised

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single call

```
function initTable(tableId, apiUrl){
 var table_element = "#" + tableId;
 if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(table_element )) {
    //remove datatable framework on the table so we can re-initialize new record
      $(table_element).DataTable().clear().destroy();
      $(table_element).html(''); //empty the table entirely
    }
//re-initialize table
     var table = $(table_element).DataTable({
                "destroy": true,
                "bprocessing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                "url": apiUrl,
                "type": "POST",
                "error": function(){
                  $("#grid_processing").css("display","none");
                  }
               }     
          });   
      }
```

Call function from anywhere like this

```
initTable('tb1','./Response1.php');
```