# Intermitient "Cannot reinitialise DataTable" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am making a project with a DataTable (https://datatables.net) and the issue I am having is pretty strange.

Sometimes when I load the page, everything works 100% and other times when I load the page I get this error from DataTables in a popup:

```
DataTables warning: table id=resdatatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

As I have said, there's no sure fire way to trigger this. If I hit refresh sometimes it will work, sometimes it will give me that error.

I am not trying to reinitialize the DataTable, so I am a bit confused on why this is happening. I checked the link in the description but I am not understanding how to remedy this.

Here is my code:

```
    let statusList = getStatusList();

function getRes(callback) { // ADDED CALLBACK
    let city = document.getElementById("cityselect").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'getreservationstable.php?city='+city,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: callback  // USED CALLBACK
    });
}

function changeCity()
{
    $('#resdatatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
}

getRes(function (result) { // APPLIED CALLBACK
  $('#resdatatable').DataTable({
     data: result,             // YOUR RESULT
      columns: [
        { data: 'id', title: 'ID' },
        { data: 'bookingdatetime', title: 'Booking Date' },
        { data: 'name', title: 'Name' },
        { data: 'class', title: 'Class' },
        { data: 'pickupdatetime', title: 'Pick up' },
        { data: 'duration', title: 'Duration' },
        { data: 'dropdatetime', title: 'Drop off' },
        { data: 'age', title: 'Age' },
        { data: 'coverage', title: 'Coverage' },
        { data: 'quote', title: 'Quote' },
        {
          data: 'status',
          title: 'Status',
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            let isKnown = statusList.filter(function(k) { return k.id === data; }).length > 0;
            if (isKnown) {
              return $('<select id ="resstatus'  + row.id + '" onchange="changeResStatus(' + row.id + ')">', {
                id: 'resstatus-' + row.id, // custom id
                value: data
              }).append(statusList.map(function(knownStatus) {
                let $option = $('<option>', {
                  text: knownStatus.text,
                  value: knownStatus.id
                });
                if (row.status === knownStatus.id) {
                  $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                return $option;
              })).on('change', function() {
                changeresstatus(row.id); // Call change with row ID
              }).prop('outerHTML');
            } else {
              return data;
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
});

/**
 * jQuery plugin to convert text in a cell to a dropdown
 */
(function($) {
  $.fn.createDropDown = function(items) {
    let oldTxt = this.text();
    let isKnown = items.filter(function(k) { return k.id === oldTxt; }).length > 0;
    if (isKnown) {
      this.empty().append($('<select>').append(items.map(function(item) {
        let $option = $('<option>', {
          text: item.text,
          value: item.id
        });
        if (item.id === oldTxt) {
          $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
        return $option;
      })));
    }
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

// If you remove the renderer above and change this to true,
// you can call this, but it will run once...
if (false) {
  $('#resdatatable > tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    $(tr).find('td').last().createDropDown(statusList);
  });
}


function getStatusList() {
  return [{
    id: 'Confirmed',
    text: 'Confirmed'
  }, {
    id: 'Unconfirmed',
    text: 'Unconfirmed'
  }, {
    id: 'Open',
    text: 'Open'
  }, {
    id: 'Closed',
    text: 'Closed'
  }, {
    id: 'Canceled',
    text: 'Canceled'
  }];
}

function changeResStatus(str1) {
    var id = str1;
    var status = document.getElementById("resstatus" + id).value;
    var mailres = "";

    var r = confirm("Change Status for ID # " + id + " to " + status + "?");
    if (r == true) {

        if (document.getElementById("resstatus" + id).value == "Confirmed"){
            var s = confirm("Send ID # " + id + " a confirmation email?");
            if (s == true) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                document.getElementById("result").setAttribute ("data-notify-msg", this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("result").setAttribute ("data-notify-type", "info");
                SEMICOLON.widget.notifications(document.getElementById("result"));
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","sendconfirmationemail.php?id="+id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
        }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").setAttribute ("data-notify-msg", this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("result").setAttribute ("data-notify-type", "info");
                SEMICOLON.widget.notifications(document.getElementById("result"));
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","changeresstatus.php?id="+id+"&status="+status,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }else{
                document.getElementById("result").setAttribute ("data-notify-msg", "Change status action aborted");
                document.getElementById("result").setAttribute ("data-notify-type", "error");
                SEMICOLON.widget.notifications(document.getElementById("result"));
    }
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#resdatatable').DataTable();

    $('#resdatatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data().id;


         $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getreservationsdetails.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {  id:data, },
        success: function(response) {
                $('#resulttitle').html("Booking ID # " + response[0].id);
                $('#resdetname').html(response[0].name);
                $('#resdetbdate').html(response[0].bookingdatetime);
                $('#resdetadd').html("<br>" + response[0].address + "<br>" + response[0].city + "<br>" + response[0].state + " " + response[0].post);
                $('#resdetphone').html(response[0].phone);
                $('#resdetemail').html(response[0].email);
                $('#resdetdln').html(response[0].dlnum);
                $('#resdetdle').html(response[0].dlexp);
                $('#resdetdlc').html(response[0].dlcountry);
                $('#resdetpickup').html(response[0].pickuploc + " " + response[0].pickupdatetime);
                $('#resdetduration').html(response[0].duration);
                $('#resdetdrop').html(response[0].droploc + " " + response[0].dropdatetime);
                $('#resdetclass').html(response[0].class);
                $('#resdetcoverage').html(response[0].coverage);
                $('#resdetage').html(response[0].age);
                $('#resdetnumofdrivers').html(response[0].numofdrivers);
                $('#resdetroadside').html(response[0].roadsideass);
                $('#resdetafterhoursdrop').html(response[0].afterhoursdrop);
                $('#resdetpromo').html(response[0].promo);
                $('#resdetquote').html(response[0].quote);
                $('#resdetaddcomments').html(response[0].name);
                $('#resdetip').html(response[0].ip);
                $("#modalresult").modal();
        }
    });



    } );
} );
```

Edit:

Upon further examination, this error seems to be caused by the line var table = $('#resdatatable').DataTable(); in $(document).ready(function() { - if I remove that line, everything works just fine. How do I make this work???

Answer (score 0):

Your error come from the fact you try to access a Database object which has not been initialized yet by `getRes()`.

Because on `$(document).ready` you were creating a first database with no options, when getRes got trigger you should update its content instead of creating a second Database() on top of the same element (which explain the "Cannot reinitialise DataTable")

Try to move the table var from your document ready to your on event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#resdatatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var table = $('#resdatatable').DataTable();
        var data = table.row( this ).data().id;
```

Or maybe init the `$('#resdatatable tbody').on` on `getRes()` as it might not have access to tbody yet:

```
getRes(function (result) { // APPLIED CALLBACK
  $('#resdatatable').DataTable({
    ...
  });

   $('#resdatatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
   ...
```

Comment: If I mover the table var from my document ready to my on event the page loads fine, but the click function doesn't work (strange). I also don't get a error in my console, just no action.

Comment: This is a very classic lifecycle issue. You need to make sure `getRest()` first initialize the DataTable with full options so it create the tbody you try to bind on your click event. The error here come from the fact `var table = $('#resdatatable').DataTable();` works as a selector if DataTable exist, or initialize one if does not exist. En error is triggered if you try to initialize a DataTable twice.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this problem:

I added a 1ms delay for the code to run:

```
setTimeout(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
                    var table = $('#resdatatable').DataTable();

    $('#resdatatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        var data = table.row( this ).data().id;

         $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getreservationsdetails.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {  id:data, },
        success: function(response) {
                $('#resulttitle').html("Booking ID # " + response[0].id);
                $('#resdetname').html(response[0].name);
                $('#resdetbdate').html(response[0].bookingdatetime);
                $('#resdetadd').html("<br>" + response[0].address + "<br>" + response[0].city + "<br>" + response[0].state + " " + response[0].post);
                $('#resdetphone').html(response[0].phone);
                $('#resdetemail').html(response[0].email);
                $('#resdetdln').html(response[0].dlnum);
                $('#resdetdle').html(response[0].dlexp);
                $('#resdetdlc').html(response[0].dlcountry);
                $('#resdetpickup').html(response[0].pickuploc + " " + response[0].pickupdatetime);
                $('#resdetduration').html(response[0].duration);
                $('#resdetdrop').html(response[0].droploc + " " + response[0].dropdatetime);
                $('#resdetclass').html(response[0].class);
                $('#resdetcoverage').html(response[0].coverage);
                $('#resdetage').html(response[0].age);
                $('#resdetnumofdrivers').html(response[0].numofdrivers);
                $('#resdetroadside').html(response[0].roadsideass);
                $('#resdetafterhoursdrop').html(response[0].afterhoursdrop);
                $('#resdetpromo').html(response[0].promo);
                $('#resdetquote').html(response[0].quote);
                $('#resdetaddcomments').html(response[0].name);
                $('#resdetip').html(response[0].ip);
                $("#modalresult").modal();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would recommand to spend some time looking at the lifecycle of your page, meaning how it loads and in which order your code is executed. Your code works fine, but code structure makes it harder to understand. This solution will only work if your getRes() function initialize your Datatable before the timeout starts (as getRes initialize `$('#resdatatable').DataTable()` then `var table = $('#resdatatable').DataTable();` works as an access instead of init).