# how to refresh datatables after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have tried few way to refresh my data table after an AJAX Call, but not working.
I tried `draw()` and .`ajax.reload()` function, but still no luck.
Any idea how to refresh it?

here my code

HTML

```
<table id="transaction_data" class="table table-hover">
                                                  <thead>
                                                  <tr>
                                                      <th>Date Created</th>
                                                      <th>User Name</th>
                                                      <th>Transaction Type</th>
                                                      <th>Amount (USD)</th>
                                                      <th>Last Update</th>
                                                      <th>Status</th>
                                                      <th>Amount Coin</th>
                                                      <th>Amount Coin Received</th>
                                                  </tr>
                                                  </thead>
                                                  <tbody>
                                                  <tr>

                                                  </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                              </table>
```

data tables script

```
var table = $("#transaction_data").DataTable({
             processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{{ url("member/deposit/data_transaction") }}',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                    { data: 'member_id', name: 'member_id' },
                     { data: 'transaction_type', name: 'transaction_type' },
                     { data: 'amount_usd', name: 'amount_usd' },
                     { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' },
                     { data: 'status', name: 'status' },
                     { data: 'amount_coin_kirim', name: 'amount_coin_kirim' },
                    { data: 'amount_coin_terima', name: 'amount_coin_terima' }
                ]
        });
```

ajax script

```
$('#formdeposit').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (grecaptcha.getResponse()) {

    var formData = {
             "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            'deposit' : $('#deposit').val(),
            'coin' : $('#coin option:selected').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '{{ asset("/member/deposit/process") }}',
            data : formData,
            dataType : 'json',
            encode : true
        })
        .done(function(data){
              console.log(data);
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
        //  

        if (data.pesan=='ok')
            {
            $('#test').html(data.html);     
            }

        else{
            $('#test').html(data.pesan);
        }   

              });

    e.preventDefault();
        table.draw(); //here I tried to refresh the datatable
    }
    else{ alert('Please Confirm The Captcha') }
});
```

Comment: try `$("#Table_id").ajax.reload();`

Comment: not working, I tried that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566541/how-to-reload-the-datatablejquery-data

Comment: after draw call ... any console error ?

Comment: @MinarMnr I got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined , maybe it's jquery related ?I tried .ajax.reload function

Comment: try that table.api().ajax.reload();

Comment: @MinarMnr Uncaught TypeError: table.api is not a function , I am tottaly confused

Comment: version of your datatable ?DataTables plug-in 1.9.x or 1.10.x

Comment: I am using datatable version 1.10.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:  try this (For - datatable version 1.10.9)

```
$('#formdeposit').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (grecaptcha.getResponse()) {

         var formData = {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            'deposit' : $('#deposit').val(),
            'coin' : $('#coin option:selected').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '{{ asset("/member/deposit/process") }}',
            data : formData,
            dataType : 'json',
            encode : true
        })
        .done(function(data){


              console.log(data);
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
        //  

        if (data.pesan=='ok')
            {
            $('#test').html(data.html);     
            }

        else{
            $('#test').html(data.pesan);
        }  
        var table = $('#transaction_data').DataTable(); 
        table.ajax.reload( null, false );

              });

        e.preventDefault();

        }
        else{ alert('Please Confirm The Captcha') }
});
```